# How to subtract the even positions from the odd ones in a 2D array and map a new array with the results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array whose first position is a Date() object. I have previously reduced the arrangement by grouping it per day. I try to reduce each daily sub-array with the results of the subtraction of the odd positions ("SALIDA") of the pairs ("ENTRADA").

**These are the data:**

```
const arrayHoras = [
  [
    "Thu Jan 02 2020 08:25:38 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Thu Jan 02 2020 13:30:43 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Thu Jan 02 2020 15:18:06 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Thu Jan 02 2020 18:12:22 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 08:35:38 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 10:15:23 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 10:59:16 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 12:25:01 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 12:31:33 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 13:20:43 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 15:28:06 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Fri Jan 03 2020 18:32:10 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Tue Jan 07 2020 08:31:46 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Tue Jan 07 2020 13:22:51 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Tue Jan 07 2020 15:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Tue Jan 07 2020 17:22:29 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Tue Jan 07 2020 17:31:59 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "ENTRADA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ],
  [
    "Tue Jan 07 2020 18:32:30 GMT+0100 (CET)",
    "SALIDA",
    "NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"
  ]
];
```

**First step**: we group the 2D arrangement by day the first position of each element

```
const gruposDias = arrayHoras.reduce((acumulador, valorActual) => {
  const dia = new Date(valorActual[0]).getDate();
  if (!acumulador[dia]) {
    acumulador[dia] = [];
  }
  acumulador[dia].push(valorActual);
  return acumulador;
}, []);

const agrupadosPorDia = Object.keys(gruposDias).map(porDia => {
  return gruposDias[porDia];
});
```

**Second step**: I try to reduce the arrangements grouped by day with the result of subtracting the seconds elapsed between the dates of the odd positions ("SALIDA") of those of the even ("ENTRADA"):

```
const entradas = [];
const salidas = [];
for (let i = 0; i < agrupadosPorDia.length; i += 1) {
  const agrupadosPorDiaI = agrupadosPorDia[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < agrupadosPorDiaI.length; j += 1) {
    if (j % 2) {
      const salidaTime = new Date(agrupadosPorDia[i][j][0]).getTime();
      salidas.push(salidaTime);
      rowSalida.push((ultRowConDatoSimulado += 2));
    } else {
      const entradaTime = new Date(agrupadosPorDia[i][j][0]).getTime();
      entradas.push(entradaTime);
    }
  }
}
console.log("entradas: ", entradas);
console.log("salidas: ", salidas);
```

**My problem**: with the second step I lose the return of the "entradas" and "salidas" arrays within each sub-array of the 2D array grouped by day.

Does anyone have the kindness to shed light on my decoder work?.

And abusing your knowledge, can you avoid the second step by expanding the array of the 2D array by expanding reduce () and map ()?. I've tried everything, I think.

### Update

Expected result

```
agrupadosPorDia: [
  [ 
    [ "05:05:05" ],
    [ "02:54:16" ]
  ],
  [
    [ "02:54:16" ],
    [ "01:39:45" ],
    [ "01:25:45" ],
    [ "00:49:10" ],
    [ "03:04:04" ]
  ],
  ​​[
    [ "04:51:05" ],
    [ "01:52:29" ],
    [ "01:00:31" ],
  ]
];
```

Comment: could you add what is the expected result?

Comment: @grodzi I've added it and sorry for forgetting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a single pass, you may assume that two consecutive horas make a call.

Then you map each call as a `<diff, date>` and group iteratively (like you did) the calls by date

Since you are not interested in the call but just the time it took (namely `diff`) you group the diff by date

```js
const arrayHoras = [["Thu Jan 02 2020 08:25:38 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Thu Jan 02 2020 13:30:43 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Thu Jan 02 2020 15:18:06 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Thu Jan 02 2020 18:12:22 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 08:35:38 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 10:15:23 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 10:59:16 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 12:25:01 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 12:31:33 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 13:20:43 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 15:28:06 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Fri Jan 03 2020 18:32:10 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Tue Jan 07 2020 08:31:46 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Tue Jan 07 2020 13:22:51 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Tue Jan 07 2020 15:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Tue Jan 07 2020 17:22:29 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Tue Jan 07 2020 17:31:59 GMT+0100 (CET)","ENTRADA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"],["Tue Jan 07 2020 18:32:30 GMT+0100 (CET)","SALIDA","NOMBRE APELLIDO APELLIDO"]]

// huge probability of being incorrect, use moment or something
const makeDelta = (a,b) => {
  const d = new Date(b - a)
  return [d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds()]
    .map(x => (x+'').padStart(2, '0'))
    .join(':')
}

const res = arrayHoras.reduce(({ dateToCalls, call }, h)=>{
  call.push(h)
  if (call.length == 2) {
    const [a, b] = call.map(x => new Date(x[0]))
    const date = a.getDate()
    const v = dateToCalls.get(date) || []
    v.push(makeDelta(a,b))
    dateToCalls.set(date, v)
    call = []
  }
  return { dateToCalls, call }
}, { dateToCalls: new Map(), call: []}).dateToCalls.values()

//res is an iterator, get an array
const out = [...res]
console.log(out)
```

Comment: It works perfectly and is exactly what I've been looking for for hours and hours. I am learning a lot of modern javascript with your answer.
Thank you so much